# Strapi DateTime

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, gatsby, strapi

I have a Datetime field in Strapi which is sending to my frontend a date and time with some sort of offset.

For example - I choose

27, November 2020 16:30PM

and on the front end of Gatbsy application after I query it with Graphql I get this

2020-11-27T15:30:00.000Z

I will need the time that the user chooses to be UTC time but I can't get it to be like that on the datepicker, I can just convert it to UTC later.

Is there a way to force the time zone and not to actually convert it to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Solved in case someone needs it

```
moment(time).utcOffset('+0000',true)
```

This will set the time zone without actually changing the time.